# Помогите понять поведение js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Всем доброго времени суток.
Плохо разбираюсь в `angular`, а `javascript` подавно, но есть задача и ее нужно решать:
Есть поле мультивыбора, в нем есть наименования товаров с ценами. Мне нужно при выборе значений товаров подсчитать их сумму.

Поле мультиселекта выглядит так:

```
<select class="chzn-select " multiple="multiple">
  <option ng-repeat="st in catalogs.state">{{ st.name  }}{{ st.price  }}</option>
</select>
```

Мне соответственно необходимо суммировать все значения которые будут выбраны в 
`{{ st.price }}`

Добрые люди дали скрипт для подсчета:

```
$scope.sumF=function(a){
    $scope.sumEnd=0;
    for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++){
      $scope.sumEnd +=parseInt(a[i]);
    }
}
```

И соответственно `html` такой:

```
<select class="chzn-select " multiple="multiple" ng-model="sum" ng-change="sumF(sum)">
  <option ng-repeat="st in catalog" value="{{st.price}}">{{st.name}}{{st.price}}</option>
</select>
```

Но появляется проблема, если я на странице вывожу значение переменной sumEnd. 
Заключается проблема в следующем: если сначала добавить пару значений в поле мультивыбора, а затем их все удалить, то в sumEnd остается значение первого выбранного эллемента(к примеру 100рублей), и потом если добавить еще один элемент то sumEnd = sumEnd(в котором почему то лежит уже значение в 100руб) + новый элемент. Хотя ожидается, что sumEnd = новый элемент.

Но вот если убрать со страницы sumEnd и выводить его значение в консоль, то такой проблемы нет! В чем у меня проблема?

Comment: $scope.sumEnd=0; вынеси за пределы функции

Answer (score -1):

По-моему будет проще сохранять список выбранных элементов, а уже от него делать сумму, сверяя присутствие в общем списке